# Sensor value through UART in ESP32 correction

Tags: c, embedded, uart, esp32, esp-idf

I am using ESP-IDF SDK to develop a small project to take sensor data through UART. I am following the data sheet which is provided by the manufacturer to parse and calculate the value of different parameter. But the output on serial is not correct and every time I am getting different output which is wrong.
Code:-

```
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "esp_system.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "driver/uart.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"

static const int RX_BUF_SIZE = 1024;

#define TXD_PIN (GPIO_NUM_4)
#define RXD_PIN (GPIO_NUM_5)
#define DELAY_IN_MS(t) (((portTickType)t*configTICK_RATE_HZ)/(portTickType)1000)

void init(void) {
    const uart_config_t uart_config = {
        .baud_rate = 4800,
        .data_bits = UART_DATA_8_BITS,
        .parity = UART_PARITY_DISABLE,
        .stop_bits = UART_STOP_BITS_1,
        .flow_ctrl = UART_HW_FLOWCTRL_DISABLE,
        .source_clk = UART_SCLK_APB,
    };
    uart_driver_install(UART_NUM_1, RX_BUF_SIZE * 2, 129, 0, NULL, 0);
    uart_param_config(UART_NUM_1, &uart_config);
    uart_set_pin(UART_NUM_1, TXD_PIN, RXD_PIN, UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE, UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE);
}


static void rx_task(void *arg)
{
    static const char *RX_TASK_TAG = "RX_TASK";
    esp_log_level_set(RX_TASK_TAG, ESP_LOG_INFO);
    uint8_t data[7] = {0};
    uint8_t PR=0,spo2=0,temprature=0;
    while (1) {
        const int rxBytes = uart_read_bytes(UART_NUM_1, data, 7, 1);
        if (rxBytes == 7) {
            printf("The rxbytes %d and %s\n",rxBytes,data);
            PR = (data[3] & 0x7F) + ((data[2] & 0x40)<<1);
            spo2 = (data[4] & 0x7F);
            temprature = (data[5] & 0x7F);
            printf("PR is %d , Spo2 is %d , temperature is %d \n",PR,spo2,temprature);
            ESP_LOGI(RX_TASK_TAG, "Read %d bytes: '%s'", rxBytes, data);
            ESP_LOG_BUFFER_HEXDUMP(RX_TASK_TAG, data, rxBytes, ESP_LOG_INFO);
            memset(data,0,7);
        }
    }
}

void app_main(void)
{
    init();
    xTaskCreate(rx_task, "uart_rx_task", 1024*2, NULL, configMAX_PRIORITIES, NULL);
}
```

The output of the program on serial monitor is:-
[image]

The data sheet provided by the manufacturer is:-
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lPATxeXXreVZkg9Ufg9BnyCrl4EsbJAj/view?usp=sharing

Correct me if I misaligned any data format to calculate the values.

Answer (score 4):

Assembling messages from an unreliable channel (serial) means you can't really rely on them always arriving in the order you expect without any issues, so you have to take precautions that you don't get junk.

The code assumes that it will always receive these 7-byte messages in 7-byte chunks, and it doesn't always work that way.  Line noise or timeouts could cause a proper message to be received in multiple chunks (say, 4 bytes then 3 bytes), or it could cause bytes to be lost.

To see if this is part of the problem, add logging on every read, not just on the ones that you expect:

```
static void rx_task(void *arg)
{
    ...
    while (1) {
        const int rxBytes = uart_read_bytes(UART_NUM_1, data, 7, 1);

        // Log ALL reads, not just the ones you expect
        ESP_LOGI(RX_TASK_TAG, "Read %d bytes: '%s'", rxBytes, data);
        ESP_LOG_BUFFER_HEXDUMP(RX_TASK_TAG, data, rxBytes, ESP_LOG_INFO);

        if (rxBytes == 7) {
                ///
        }
    }
}
```

This will probably confirm my hunch.

In any case, you can't ever rely on the fixed-size messages because if it gets out of sync *once*, it won't ever recover. This means you have to build in your own protections.

Reading the data sheet for the sensor, it says that the *first* byte of every 7-byte message has the high bit set, so this is perfect for resynchronization: you ignore everything until you get that start byte, then read 6 more bytes, then you have a full message.

So you end up needing *two* buffers: one for the message you're assembling, and one for doing raw I/O from the sensor, copying to the real message buffer as you verify the sync.

A quick-and-dirty method would look like this:

```
static void rx_task(void *arg)
{
    static const char *RX_TASK_TAG = "RX_TASK";
    esp_log_level_set(RX_TASK_TAG, ESP_LOG_INFO);

    // sensor message we're trying to build
    uint8_t message[7] = {0};
    uint8_t *msgnext = message;

    while (1) {
        uint8_t inbuf[7];

        const int rxBytes = uart_read_bytes(UART_NUM_1, inbuf, sizeof inbuf, 1);

        ESP_LOGI(RX_TASK_TAG, "Read %d bytes: '%s'", rxBytes, inbuf);
        ESP_LOG_BUFFER_HEXDUMP(RX_TASK_TAG, inbuf, rxBytes, ESP_LOG_INFO);

        // error/timeout? do something?
        if (rxBytes <= 0) continue;

        for (int i = 0; i < rxBytes; i++)
        {
            const uint8_t b = inbuf[i];

            if (b & 0x80)
            {
                // First byte of a message, reset the buffer
                 msgnext = message;
                *msgnext++ = b;
            }   

            else if (msgnext == message)
            {
                // not synced yet, ignore this byte
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                *msgnext++ = b;

                if ((msgnext - message) == sizeof message)
                {
                    // WE FOUND A FULL MESSAGE
                    uint8_t PR   = (message[3] & 0x7F) + ((message[2] & 0x40)<<1);
                    uint8_t spo2 = (message[4] & 0x7F);
                    uint8_t temperature = (message[5] & 0x7F);
                    printf("PR is %d, Spo2 is %d, temperature is %d\n",
                         PR,spo2,temperature);

                    msgnext = message; // reset to empty the buffer
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is your raw I/O is done into `inbuf`, and it starts by looking for the sync byte (with the high bit set), and that tells you to start copying data to the real sensor buffer `message`. Once you get 7 bytes, it shows the result and resets the buffer.

And even if you have a few bytes of valid `message` data, if *another* SYNC byte comes in, it assumes the previous message was messed up, so it throws it away and starts a new fresh buffer.

You can add more here, such as support for timeouts, or detecting/logging when a partial message is discarded, but in no case can you avoid this data-framing layer.

Also, it's not necessary that the I/O buffer `inbuf` to be the same as the message size, and it might make sense to read from the UART in one-byte chunks; in a multi-tasking operating system I probably wouldn't do this, but in the ESP environment it might make sense - dunno. That would simplify the looping some.

**EDIT** Looking at your actual data dumps, it's clear that your messages are not framed properly because even though you have 7 bytes, the SYNC byte (with the high bit set) is found somewhere in the middle, but not the same place each time. Clearly this is a framing issue.

[image: Data capture showing misaligned framing]